# Combining 2 HashMaps and returning String

Tags: java, hashmap

Im working on an Digital Technology assessment. It's a Program to store a customers Pizzas, Extras and information at a Pizza store. In my confirmation window, I need to print all the pizzas he is ordering. Here are my hashmaps:

```
private HashMap<Integer, String> pizzas = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
private HashMap<String, Integer> pizzas_count = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

And my addPizza method, aswell as my getOrder method

```
public void addPizza(String name){
    if(pizzas.containsValue(name)){
        int count = pizzas_count.get(name);
        pizzas_count.remove(name);
        pizzas_count.put(name, count++);
    }else{
        pizzas.put(pizzas.size(), name);
        pizzas_count.put(name, 1);
    }
}
public String getOrder(){
    String order = "";
    System.out.println(pizzas.toString());
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        if(pizzas.get(i) != null){
            System.out.println(pizzas.get(i));
            order = order + pizzas_count.get(pizzas.get(i)) + " x " + pizzas.get(i) + "\n";
        }
    }
    return order;
}
```

My console is showing "{0=bbq}", even after adding multiple pizzas.

The getOrder method is returning (After adding 1 pizza and 1 extra):

```
PIZZAS 
null x null
EXTRAS 
1 x pasta
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to make a `Pizza` class, that'd simplify things a lot

Comment: This is in the Order class. Heres the order class http://pastebin.com/QWDDk2Qm

Comment: You could still create the `Pizza ` class tho

Comment: You put the `Pizza` class in the `Order` class. Kind of like you did, except this time it's a class and not a bunch of `HashMaps`. `HashMaps` have their place, but I don't think this is it.

Answer (score 2):

After first insertion of `bbq` pizza to pizza map, any subsequent insertion will just increment `"bbq"`'s counter as the following code suggest:

```
if(pizzas.containsValue(name)){ // if "bbq" already exist, increment its counter
                    // but is it really happening?
        int count = pizzas_count.get(name);
        pizzas_count.remove(name);
        pizzas_count.put(name, count++); 
              // this line is not having any effect why?
    }else{
        pizzas.put(pizzas.size(), name);
        pizzas_count.put(name, 1);
    }
```

in your code `pizzas_count.put(name, count++);` is not having any effect at all. This line is actually equivalent to:

```
{
    int count = pizzas_count.get(name);
    pizzas_count.put(name, count); // count wasn't changed
    count = count + 1;
   }
```

Instead do `pizzas_count.put(name, ++count);`. Rest of the things are working correctly as you have written. ***After fixing it***, the following input code:

```
    addPizza("pizza");
    addPizza("extra");
    addPizza("pizza");
    System.out.println(getOrder());
```

produces following output:

```
{0=pizza, 1=extra}
pizza
extra
2 x pizza
1 x extra
```

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't quite what I was looking for, but you have definitely helped me further down the road. I have added what getOrder is returning to the main question.

Comment: updated the answer too. And I am thinking it is returning fine if you set `++counter` instead of  `counter++`

Comment: Now, its returning
PIZZAS
EXTRAS

Comment: A nice design would be declaring a `Pizza` class with `String pizzaType` and `int pizzaCount` and creating a `HashMap` with it. However read yuor code from beginning to end one more time thoroughly.

Comment: I don't think I see anything wrong..... Here is an updated version of the class. http://pastebin.com/uRHQZHbQ

Comment: check line 40 inside `addExtra()` function: `extras.put(pizzas.size() + 1, name);`. adding extra with pizza's size() with +1 ?!

Comment: Well, I fixed that, now I see all the extras. As for the pizzas, Im not seeing anything1

Comment: sorry, i don't see any other wrong which might prevent you from getting the correct output.